# Объединить запросы из цикла в главный

Tags: php, mysqli

Задача оптимизировать работу с планировщиком задач в CRM. Вынести все запросы из цикла (их там до 15шт - а это пипец) в один главный и уже с результатом работать в цикле. Я попробовал сделать через LEFT JOIN, все было радужно и хорошо до момента, когда надо было в запрос добавить базу заполненных полей лида, которому привязана задача.

```
$remRemember = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
                                    `tk`.`end_datetime`,
                                    `tk`.`id_connection`,
                                    `tk`.`id_staff_contractor`,
                                    `cb`.`id`,
                                    `cb`.`timezone`,
                                    `tz`.`id`, 
                                    `ld`.`id`, 
                                    `icn`.`id_data`, 
                                    `st`.`id_staff`, 
                                    `tk`.`id` AS `id_task`,
                                    `tz`.`timezone_plus` AS `timezone_plus`, 
                                    `ld`.`id` AS `id_contact`, 
                                    `cb`.`id` AS `id_cabinet`, 
                                    `st`.`id_staff` AS `id_staff_contractor` 
                                FROM tasks tk
                                    LEFT JOIN cabinet cb ON cb.id = tk.id_cabinet
                                    LEFT JOIN timezone tz ON tz.id = cb.timezone 
                                    LEFT JOIN lids ld ON ld.id = tk.id_connection 
                                    LEFT JOIN staff st ON st.id_staff = tk.id_staff_contractor
                                    LEFT JOIN input_content icn ON icn.id_data = ld.id 
                                WHERE 
                                    tk.end_datetime 
                                BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
                                ORDER BY 
                                    tk.end_datetime");
```

Все хорошо работает, пока я не добавляю выборку из `input_content`. В момент вывода результата основной таблицы и вывода данных из `input_content` результатом 27 строк, но в цикле происходит дублирование данных основной таблицы.

Суть в том, чтобы использовать данные из этих таблиц в цикле и там уже отправлять напоминания.

Хотел попробовать заносить все в массивы перед циклом, а потом уже работать с ними, но базы `lids` и `input_content` достаточно объемные (10ки тысяч) и заносить все их данные в массивы кажется жутью...

Как лучше сделать?

Comment: 1) А точно нужны ЛЕВЫЕ джойны? 2) А почему не `JOIN input_content icn ON icn.id_data = tk.id_connection`?

Comment: Значит в input_content у вас более 1 записи с указанным id_data. Надо определиться какая именно запись из этой таблицы нужна. А если вдруг нужна информация из нескольких записей, то решить какая и как вытянуть ее в виде одной единственной строки. В зависимости от принятого решения дополнить условия в ON для точного определения записи и/или применить ко всему запросу group by, который соберет записи обратно в одну, при этом к колонкам из input_content надо будет применить какую нибудь агрегатную функцию, например sum() или может group_concat()

Comment: В особо тяжелых случаях возможно научиться обрабатывать в php несколько строк как одну, не забыв добавить в запрос order by что бы связанные записи выбирались точно друг за другом

Comment: @Mike Я уже понял, что он работает таким образом из-за нескольких полей в базе input_content, но это все правильно, так как для каждого поля Лида отдельная строка в базе. Вот и теперь мучаюсь по этому поводу =( Может быть, формировать запрос к сторонней функции в которой будут обрабатываться и доставаться нужные данные из таблицы input_content и соответственно отправлять уведомления. Как вариант... Все лучше, чем 15 запросов на итерацию...

Comment: Ну я вижу, что у вас в запросе только id_data из этой таблицы. Может сделать с ней group_concat ? (и остальные поля в group by добавить). Тогда у вас будет одно поле, в котором окажутся все id_data через запятую (или другой разделитель) и тогда в php можно будет explode сделать и получить массив